# How can I add a taxonomy terms as a CSS class to my views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I would like to add a taxonomy term as a CSS class to each view result. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you precise your question please? View result means  in a Views results? In content type display? ...

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, in View results.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field with the taxonomy term and then exclude it from the view.

Then add as many fields you wish to present, such as Title.

Finally, add a global: custom text, and specify for example:

```
<div class="[field_tags]">[title]</div>
```

Replace with your field names obviously. You can consult the "replacement patterns" that the Views module kindly provides.

Comment: In fact, you don't necessarily need global text, you can do the same on the last field in your list (eg title), by using the 'rewrite results' option.

Comment: If you'd prefer having more control over the method Wtower mentioned, you can also override one of your View's template files (view-view-fields.tpl.php for example) and include the proper HTML markup and print out the fields via PHP there instead. I find it makes things a little easier when coming back to do maintenance if my code is contained in theme files rather than within the Views UI. Just my two cents on the matter :)

Comment: Thank you, Wtower and AlexK - I actually do have a views template file, but I'm not sure how I could use the taxonomy term token as a css class in my template. I tried <div class="[term]"> but that didn't quite work out. Any ideas...?